# Count the item from an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

How can I count in a multidimensional array the number of element with a special condition ?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [item] => 'Banana'
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [item] => 'Banana'

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [item] => 'Cherry'
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [item] => 'Apple'

        )
)
```

For example, for this array I should find `2` for `Banana`.

Si I tried:

```
$i=0;
foreach($array as $arr) {
    if($arr[item]=='Banana') { $i++; }
}
```

Is there a better solution please ?

Thanks.

Comment: What is wrong with that solution?

Comment: And I guess you will be thrown with error in if condition `item` is without quotes!

Comment: you could combine `sizeof()` and `array_filter()`

Comment: just use the one liner print_r(array_count_values(array_column($your_array,'item')));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1:**

Using built-in functions - [`array_column`](http://php.net/array_column) and [`array_count_values`](http://php.net/array_count_values):

```
print_r(array_count_values(array_column($arr,'item')));
```

---

**Method 2:**

Using foreach with simple logic of making your fruit as key and its count as value:

```
$arr = [
["item"=>"Banana"],
["item"=>"Banana"],
["item"=>"Cherry"],
["item"=>"Apple"]
];

$countArr = [];

foreach ($arr as $value) {
    $item = $value['item'];
    if(array_key_exists($item, $countArr))   // If key exists, increment its value
        $countArr[$item]++;
    else                                     // Otherwise, assign new key
        $countArr[$item] = 1;
}

print_r($countArr);
```

---

**Final result** in both case would be:

```
Array
(
    [Banana] => 2
    [Cherry] => 1
    [Apple] => 1
)
```

---

So when you want Banana's count, you can get it like this:

```
echo $countArr['Banana'];
```

Comment: Your solution is more interesting than mine. :)

Comment: @FAD Check out the updated one! Simplest with builtin functions

Comment: In your first method, how can I specify the item I want to count (i.e.: `Banana`) ?

Comment: Both method returns the array of count, so you can fetch `echo $countArr['Banana'];`

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_count_values()`, it is pretty straight forward:

```
foreach($array as $arr) {
    $new[]  =   $arr['item'];
}

print_r(array_count_values($new));
```

On a side note, there isn't anything wrong with your approach, unless you want to count all values. Also on a side note, I think you'll find a `foreach()` will eek out a slightly faster time than `array_column()`, especially on a large array.